# How do i enclose the Single quotes in double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a php variable that needs to be interpreted in javascript how do i do this

```
var cntr = "<?php echo $j;?>";
var opt = "<?php echo $options;?>";
var opt_selected = "<?php echo get_options($val['SOMEVARIABLE'],$opt); ?>";
var reference = "<?php echo $val["RFDREFVAL"];?>";
```

How do i correct the above statements iam getting Javascript error "unterminated string contant " .what is the Best to have this php variables interpreted

Comment: What are typical values of the PHP expressions `$j`, `$options`, `get_options($val['SOMEVARIABLE'],$opt);`, and `$val["RFDREFVAL"]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
var reference = "<?php echo json_encode($val["RFDREFVAL"]);?>";
```

In the general case, let's say you have a PHP expression you want to put into a Javascript string.  Let's call the PHP expression BLAH_BLAH_BLAH.  Use:

```
var my_variable_name = "<?php echo json_encode(BLAH_BLAH_BLAH);?>";
```

So for example, if your expression is:

```
StuClass::getopt($val["CDE"],$opt)
```

then you want:

```
var my_variable_name = "<?php echo json_encode(StuClass::getopt($val["CDE"],$opt));?>";
```

Comment: I tried this option but it is giving unterminated string constant var opt_selected = "<?php echo StuClass::getopt(json_encode($val["CDE"]),$opt);?>";

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your PHP code is producing output that contains quotes and/or backslashes. Use `addslashes` to escape these before using them in JavaScript. For example:

```
var cntr = "<?php echo addslashes($j);?>";
```

and similarly for the other variables.

Comment: I tried this option but it is giving unterminated string constant var opt_selected = "<?php echo StuClass::getopt(addslashes($val["CDE"]),$opt);?>

Comment: The `addslashes` should be the outermost call. Try `echo addslashes(StuClass::getopt($val["CDE"],$opt));`